# Input value does not show up in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to populate textarea using the input value. But it is not working. Any solution to this issue?

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModelName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "textbox-css", @Value = "ViewData.Model.ModelName" } })
```

Comment: If I remove  @Value = "ViewData.Model.ModelName", the html code will not have the value attribute to fill the textbox

Comment: Remove the quotes around `ViewData.Model.ModelName"`.

Comment: You should never attempt to override the `value` attribute (you will not get correct 2-way model binding). If you set the value of property `ModelName` in the controller, then its value will be displayed in the view.

Comment: Of course it works. Show your controller code - you obviously have other problems with your code.

Comment: There are no `EditorFor()` methods [that take HtmlAttributes as a parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: @ErikPhilips, Its the second overload (with parameter `object additionalViewData`) but only applicable for MVC 5.1+ (see also [What's New in ASP.NET MVC 5.1](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Bootstrap))

Comment: Actually it works for MVC 2 at the very least up.  I just contend that it's very bad practice to send HtmlAttributes to an editor.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, If below, 5.1, then it would only work if using a custom `EditorTemplate` (and the template read the `additionalViewData` and applied it to an element)

Comment: @StephenMuecke very true. `@Html.TextBox("", Model, ViewData["htmlAttributes"])` (for example) would get very similar results prior to 5.1

Comment: Other than the obvious `string literal` instead of a `variable` the issue will be with using both ViewData and a Model, neither of which you have provided in the question.  You need to show: the `@model x` at the top of the view; where/how you are setting ViewData; details of the view model (the 'x' in `@model x`) with `ModelName` and how you are setting this in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove quotes from `@Value = "ViewData.Model.ModelName"`, because you are sending a string to Value property, not the content of ModelName property.

But why don't you use the TextArea helper? Like:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ModelName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "textbox-css" })
```

It's not common set the value property like you are doing, I don't know if it works, actually. I think this is not a good way to do that. You should use the TextAreaFor(x => x.Property) or EditFor(x => x.Property) directly, instead of set the value property, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to manually populate the value property with the ViewData, remove the `@Value = "ViewData.Model.ModelName"`. I think the problem is your ViewData name conflict with the property of the model (both have the name "ModelName").

Try changing the ViewData property name to something else. Works for me when I have an issue with unpopulated `DropDownListFor`